# Key expiration policy for 3DES / TDES / Triple DES

Tags: 3des, key-reuse

I have a system that signs plain text messages using a message authentication code (MAC) encrypted with 3-key Triple DES. The short message is used on connection to establish a session key, so it would take an attacker a long time to compile a lot of plaintext / MAC examples.

I need to establish a key expiration policy that says "keys shall be changed at interval X" to  maintain security. What is a reasonable time limit considering only the cryptographic threats?

1. From the reading that I have done, I expect that a brute-force attack (Lucks attack, ref. rfc4772, effective 108 bits) is not practical within the lifetime of the system (30 years) and is not a threat that requires periodic changing of keys. Is this true?
2. There seem to be some attacks that benefit from compiling a lot of plaintext / ciphertext examples. A reasonable key policy would be to change the key before enough examples could be collected. What is a reasonable limit, considering the known attacks on Triple DES? Something I read (edit: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4772) suggested 2^32 blocks was such a limit.

Comment: 1) Which MAC construction are you use? 2) Why choose 3DES over HMAC or even AES? 3) Attacks become likely as you approach 2^32 blocks, you should stay significantly below that value.

Comment: 1) It is a type of CBC-MAC, but I'm not familiar enough with the literature to know how "standard" or special it is. If you care to read about it, google "Subset-037". Used in train signalling. 2) Good comment, but this is a "legacy" system that I cannot change. 3) The CBC-MAC digests the message in CBC mode and cooks it down to a single block of ciphertext. I assume that this only counts as one block (for purposes of key wear) even if the message is longer. Is that correct?

Comment: I would do "prior to $2^{31}$ blocks of plaintext" between key changes, for the purposes of attacks it is NOT just the last block, but the total encrypted blocks.

Comment: I hope you mean "I have a legacy system with Triple DES" rather than "I am building a system with Triple DES", unless you are being compelled. Incidentally, I believe it has 80 bits of security, from known/chosen plaintext attacks.

Comment: @Richie, thanks for your input - 2^31 seems like an appropriate limit also considering the comment from CodesInChaos. 

One clarification though - the message itself is sent in plain text with only a 64-bit (one block) MAC for authentication. In this way, the message is not "encrypted" but "authenticated" with a single block MAC. However, the entire message (about 5 blocks) is the input to the MAC algorithm. In this way, the MAC is only a single block of "encrypted" text. Would you still interpret the message length as the deciding factor for key wear?

Comment: @Nathan - I am building a new system (which is why I need to establish a key policy) that interfaces with an existing system that uses Triple DES (which is why I cannot choose anything else).

I should specify that I am using 3-key TDES. The most useful reference I have found so far (see edited question) puts the strength at 108 bits. Do you have another reference for the 80-bit strength?

Comment: @JohnPrice Sorry my mistake, [NIST](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/key_mgmt/documents/Transitioning_CryptoAlgos_070209.pdf) say 2 key is 80, they seem to think 3 key is 112 bits. Anyway, this is a side discussion to your implementation question, you need to use it so fair enough.

Comment: @Nathan, Thanks for the NIST reference, that helps!